# Python telnet how to use when username and password not required

Tags: python, telnet

I have a requirement to telnet from one Windows PC to another. I would like to log in and issue commands (and see replies) using Python.

This is very easy to achieve this in my local cmd window: 
Call up cmd and type `'telnet REMOTECOMPUTERNAME'`.
Reply in window is:

> 'Welcome to the ChyronHego telnet server on REMOTECOMPUTERNAME'

I can issue commands (e.g. `'V\6\1\\'`) by typing directly into prompt.
Remote system responds by carrying out task or issuing error message in prompt.

(I have tried using `telnetlib` and `system.process` and `os` without any result so far)

Does anyone know how I can achieve this programmatically using Python?

Many thanks in advance.
Ian

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subprocess module to perform a telnet cmd on windows. Additional parameters can be added to the list as a separate element. EX:["telnet", "HOST", 'V']

```
import subprocess    
p = subprocess.Popen(["telnet", "HOST"], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply Rakesh - this gives the error: 'windowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.